# Address book not visible to registered users

Tags: 8, commerce

We are using drupal commece 2 on drupal 8 and I noticed, that `/user/xx/address-book/` only works for the admin user, not for normal registered ones.

It appears to be a permission issue, but under `/admin/people/permissions` I can not find anything billing / shipping / address related.

Anybody knows which box to tick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after checking a bit the commerce module, it looks like this is tied to profile view permissions and also addresses are linked to customer profiles.

I made it work by enabling the following **Profile** permissions under `/admin/people/permissions`:

- Customer: Create profiles (enables to create new addresses)
- Customer: Delete own profiles (enables to delete addresses)
- Customer: Update own profiles
- Customer: View own profiles (enables the address-book tab for registered customers)
- View own profiles (just in case)